# How to handle "Unauthenticated" when User is logged out but is on an authenticated route?

Tags: vue.js

Let us say the user is on the Settings page but goes away from the keyboard for a while.

Technically the user is not authenticated but is able to "surf" his/her settings page until the user hits a page where some new data from the server is requested.

Currently, I just catch the "Unauthenticated" response and reload the page so the user gets to /login.

I'm using Laravel, but the setting page is based on Vue + Vue router. The setting is thus a single page but acts as it has many.

So how do you handle this kind of situation? Are you checking the authentication status like every 1 minute?

Comment: depends very much on what user-experience you would want to provide. banks for example have a timer that runs down and you get logged then. others try to keep the connection alive through polling the backend for changes constantly.

Comment: @phoet the last tip is quite interesting. I'm going to find out how it works, thanks

Comment: Unless you are dealing with really sensitive information I would not worry about this too much. For example a banking app would obviously have to automatically log you out after x seconds. If you are not dealing with such information you can simply let further actions which require authentication to redirect the user or throw an error message.